# Spectroscopic constants - explanation

Tags: spectroscopy, theoretical-chemistry, ab-initio

I'm a beginner in spectroscopy and I have troubles understanding papers describing values of spectroscopic constants. [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257738988_Spectroscopic_constants_and_molecular_properties_of_X2Sg_A2Pu_B2Su_and_D2Pg_electronic_states_of_the_N2_ion), for example, describes constants $T_e, R_e, \omega_e, \omega_ex_e, B_e, \alpha_e, D_0$ and $D_e$.

I can see, that $R_e$ is an internuclear distance, but I have no idea, what are the remaining constants.

Could you provide some brief explanation? Preferably with picture of some potential energy curve(s), if possible, as I find it much easier to understand such concepts from schemes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find plots and further explanations online (as I easily did). This is a homework-type question, yet I do feel that the information request for diatomic molecular spectroscopic constants warrants at least this partial answer. See [this writeup for the "Vibronic Absorption Spectrum of Molecular Iodine"](http://websites.uwlax.edu/aloh/pdf_files/chm313_pdf/Manual_current/chm313_Expt6_I2.pdf) for more details and illustrations.

From [NIST](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7553562&Mask=1000):

T$_e$ minimum electronic energy (cm$^{-1}$)

R$_e$ internuclear distance (Å)

ω$_e$ vibrational constant – first term (cm$^{-1}$)

ω$_e$x$_e$  vibrational constant – second term (cm$^{-1}$)

B$_e$ rotational constant in equilibrium position (cm$^{-1}$)

α$_e$ rotational constant – first term (cm$^{-1}$)

D$_e$ centrifugal distortion constant (cm$^{-1}$)

β$_e$ rotational constant – first term, centrifugal force (cm$^{-1}$)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birge%E2%80%93Sponer_method):

D$_0$ dissociation energy (cm$^{-1}$)

Answer (score 3):

The subscript $e$ means measurements relating to the minimum of the internuclear separation, i.e. at the bottom of the potential energy. Many textbooks do not use the subscript $e$ at all but the meaning is the same.

The $D_0$ by contrast is the dissociation energy measured from the lowest vibrational energy level ($n=0$), some books also quote $D_e$ which is the energy from the lowest point on the potential energy and so this is $D_0$ plus the zero point energy. However, $D_e$ may also be the centrifugal distortion constant and has the same units as $B_e$. The context in which it is used will determine what it means, i.e. if the use is in determining the rotational energy $D_e$ (or just $D$) will be the centrifugal distortion constant.

The term $x_e$ is the anharmonicity constant and is dimensionless and $\alpha_e$ is the vibration-rotation coupling constant, and has the same units as $B_e$. (It describes the fact that as the molecule has a different bond length in vibrational level $n=1$ than in $n=0$, and that in $n=2$ from $n=1$ etc, consequently the rotational constant $B$ has to be modified). The other terms are described in the first answer.

However, there is a wrinkle, the fact that $\omega$ is used and not $v$ for frequency means that *angular frequencies* are being used. They are related as $\omega =2\pi v$. The frequency $\omega $ has units $\mathrm{radian\,s  ^{-1}}$ and $v$ units of $\mathrm{\,s^{-1}}$. Some books use $v$ some $\omega$; it is really quite messy you just have to be careful.